# internet explorer issues

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, joomla

Hello I developing a website in Joomla  the website is working fine in Mozilla, Safari and chrome but when I render it in Internet explorer it gives following error.

Please enlighten me on this.....

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Fri, 23 Oct 2009 05:15:31 UTC


Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/flagdown/index.php?option=com_companies&amp;view=profile&amp;TAXI_ID=a936db2fe93260547e75782e250d672c&amp;COMPANY_NAME=asd1234&amp;CONTACT_NAME=aa&amp;ADDRESS=aaa&amp;SERVICE_EMAIL=ankit@aa.com&amp;ADMIN_EMAIL=aahorror@aa.com&amp;DISPATCH_PHNO=5555555555&amp;ADMIN_PHNO=5555555555&amp;NO_OF_TAXIS=57&amp;ALLOW_AD=&amp;TOTAL_REBATE=0.000000&amp;USERNAME=ankit
```

Comment: Do you have script elements in containers that are modified by the script?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've got some Javascript that's attempting to modify the DOM before it's ready. Are you using a JS library, by any chance? They really help with this; for example, the jQuery solution would be...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Any code you put in here won't run until everything is ready.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try validating your HTML using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), to make sure you've properly closed all your elements (and also that your HTML is valid).

Then, make sure you're not interfering with the DOM before the page is fully loaded.

To know more we'd have to see your HTML source code, and any JavaScript (particularly any JS that manipulates the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to malformed XHTML check out [this blog post](http://tommcfarlin.com/2008/04/23/ies-kb927917-error/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this with validating your HTML and using:

```
window.onload = function() { /* code here instead so you are sure dom is complete */ }
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Any code you put in here won't run until everything is ready.
});
```

Then you may want to set a Timeout.

eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Any code you put in here won't run until everything is ready.
    }, 500);
});
```

Sometimes IE needs just a lil' more time.